# Creating a Contingency table in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, contingency

I want to create a contingency table in Pandas.  I can do it with the following code but I wondered if there is a pandas function that would do it for me.

For a reproducible example:

```
toy_data #json
'{"Light":{"321":"no_light","476":"night_light","342":"lamp","454":"lamp","25":"night_light","53":"night_light","120":"night_light","346":"night_light","360":"lamp","55":"no_light","391":"night_light","243":"no_light","101":"night_light","377":"night_light","124":"no_light","368":"lamp","400":"no_light","247":"night_light","270":"lamp","208":"night_light"},"Nearsightedness":{"321":"No","476":"Yes","342":"Yes","454":"Yes","25":"No","53":"Yes","120":"Yes","346":"No","360":"No","55":"Yes","391":"Yes","243":"No","101":"No","377":"Yes","124":"No","368":"No","400":"No","247":"No","270":"Yes","208":"No"}}'

toy_data.head()
    Light       Nearsightedness
321 no_light       No
476 night_light    Yes
342 lamp           Yes
454 lamp           Yes
25  night_light    No

df = pd.DataFrame(toy_data.groupby(['Light', 'Nearsightedness']).size())

df = df.unstack('Nearsightedness')

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

df
Nearsightedness No  Yes
Light       
lamp             2  3
night_light      5  5
no_light         4  1
```

Comment: What a joy to see a perfect question - a great [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a working solution, and desired output!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[pd.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) will do the trick:

```
pd.crosstab(df.Light, df.Nearsightedness)
```

Output:

```
Nearsightedness  No  Yes
Light
lamp              2    3
night_light       5    5
no_light          4    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
res = pd.crosstab(df['Light'], df['Nearsightedness'].eq('Yes'))

print(res)

Nearsightedness  False  True 
Light                        
lamp                 2      3
night_light          5      5
no_light             4      1
```